# as3 Button gets disabled, no error pop ups and no idea how it's happening and how to fix it

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm working on a AS3 ball game, currently i have 2 scenes home and baseball. home has a button which sends the player to the baseball which has a little ball catching game. the button in question is on the home page, it works fine when the FLA loads and you have to click the reb button to load the game but once the game over it sends the player back to the home and the button doesnt want to load.

Comment: I don't have Flash installed but using scenes ususally leads to errors, when scenes are not entered and exited cleanly, you'll end up in a mess.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic when i use frames i still get the same problem ill edit my post so you can see the full code on both screens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice that when you return to the `home` scene, the output continues to trace "return". This is because you are never removing your `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener for `exit` or resetting the `Score` to 0.

```
function exit (evt:Event) : void 
{
    if (Score == 2)
        {
        Score = 0;
        trace("return");
        clearInterval(interval);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, exit); // <--- added line
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,Ballgame);
        gotoAndPlay(1,"home");
        }
}
```

This will fix your issue with the button not working in your home scene, however, you'll want to add some code to clean up the display list (as it will still show all of the baseballs that you generated on the ballgame scene).